# Swift SceneKit - Color difference between editor and simulation

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm working on a basic 3D SceneKit-based game for IOS and I have observed that the colors I have picked in the editor and the ones shown in simulation don't match (screenshot https://pasteboard.co/HVWdnnK.png)

The code is pretty much the same as the default SceneKit game code, only I've commented the parts that configure the lights and everything because they are already manually configured in the editor (I have a feeling that I might be missing something here)

Would appreciate if you could take a look.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    // create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!       
    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "corner-camera", recursively: true)!
    // cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    // scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)        
    // place the camera
    // let camera = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "corner-camera", recursively: true)!
    // cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)        
    // create and add a light to the scene
    // let lightNode = SCNNode()
    // lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    // lightNode.light!.type = .omni
    // lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
    // scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    // create and add an ambient light to the scene
    // let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    // ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    // ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
    // ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
    // scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    // retrieve the ship node
    // let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!        
    // animate the 3d object
    // ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))        
    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView        
    // set the scene to the view
    scnView.scene = scene        
    // set camera to corner-camera
    scnView.pointOfView = cameraNode        
    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    // scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
    // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    // scnView.showsStatistics = true

    // configure the view
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    // add a tap gesture recognizer
    // let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    // scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing is that the simulator uses the OpenGL renderer while Xcode and iOS devices default to the Metal renderer.

Also the Xcode editor has several options to customise how the scene in rendered and the "[default lighting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523812-autoenablesdefaultlighting)" option might not match the one used by the app.

Comment: Yeah, rendered perfectly on the machine. Thanks a lot!